# Is there a way to go from Malaysia to Indonesia by Ferry?

Tags: public-transport, ferries, indonesia, malaysia

We are planing to travel

1. From Singapore to Kuala Lumpur by train,
2. Kuala Lumpur to Indonesia by bus and ferry

I figured out the first part and still blur about the second part.
Does anyone know how to go from Malaysia to Indonesia by public transport ferry? The destination of the Indonesia can be adjusted depend on the ferry service availability.

And the port of the Indonesia should have Immigration clearance facility. because we are not Indonesians.

Answer (score 5):

There are boats going everyday:

- From Singapore to Batam Island  (Riau archipelago)
- From Klang (KL harbor) to Tujung Balai (Nord Sumatra)
- From Malaka to Dumai (Sumatra/Riau province)

Except for the Singapore-Batam, information can be hard to find, but I took all of those boats in a not too distant past.
I know there are visa on arrival at Dumai and Batam. Probably also at Tanjung Balai (They have at least basic immigration. I was traveling from Indonesia).

Technically, I should also mention a ferry from Tawau to Tarakan (no visa on arrival when I was there, but it was in 2012) in case you go to Borneo.

Answer (score 3):

According to Lonely Planet, [Malaysia to Indonesia by ferry](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/asia-south-east-asia-islands-peninsula/topics/malaysia-singapore-to-indonesia-by-boat) can be a bit dicey. Some cursory other research does not look promising either.

I would recommend taking AirAsia from Kuala Lumpur to Medan or Pekanbaru. It might be slightly pricier than a ferry but would be more convenient and have a lower likelihood of immigration related friction.

There is a ferry from Singapore to Batam island, but I don't think that's what you have in mind.